# Propositions concerning a differentiable function.

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

I am trying to solve the following problems:

Suppose that f: (0, $\infty$) $\to$ $\Re$ is differentiable.  Determine whether each of the following statements is true or false:

(a) If $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ f(x) exists and is finite, and $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ f'(x) = b, then b = 0.

(b) If $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ f(x) exists and is finite, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ f'(x) = 0.

(c) If $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ f'(x) = 0, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ f(x) exists.

(d) If $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ f'(x) = 0, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ f(x)/x = 0.

I have drawn pictures for (a), and I think that it is true.  However, I'm not sure how to prove this.
I've managed to find a counterexample for (c).
I'm not sure how to approach (b) and (d), although I have noticed that (a) and (b) are related.

Could I have suggestions on how to approach these questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) True. By the MVT we find for each $n\in\mathbb N$ an $x_n\in[n,n+1]$ such that $f(n+1)-f(n)=f'(x_n)$. Since the limits exist we have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}f'(x_n) \\ &=\lim_{n\to\infty}[f(n+1)-f(n)]\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n+1)-\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)-\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\\&=0.
\end{align*}

(b) False. Consider $f(x)=\sin(x^2)/x$. Then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$, but the limit of $f'(x)=2\cos(x^2)-\sin(x^2)/x^2$ as $x\to\infty$ does not exist.

(c) False. Consider $f(x)=\sin(\sqrt{x})$. Then $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(\sqrt{x})$ does not exist, but $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\cos(\sqrt{x})/(2\sqrt{x})=0$.

(d) True. Fix $\epsilon>0$. Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$ we find some $c>0$ such that $|f'(x)|<\epsilon$ for each $x\geq c$. Then
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{f(x)}{x}\right|&=\left|\frac{1}{x}\int_0^xf'(t)dt\right|\\&\leq\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x|f'(t)|dt\\&=\frac{1}{x}\left(\int_0^c|f'(t)|dt+\int_c^x|f'(x)|dt\right)\\&\leq\frac{1}{x}\int_0^c|f'(t)|dt+\frac{(x-c)\epsilon}{x}\to\epsilon
\end{align*}
as $x\to\infty$. This shows that $\limsup_{x\to\infty}|f(x)/x|\leq\epsilon$, and since this is true for each $\epsilon>0$ we must have $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)/x=0$.

Comment: For (a): I think that the Mean Value Theorem can only be applied to a function f when f is continuous on some closed interval.  Here, we haven't assumed (and can't assume) that f is continuous, have we?

Comment: Since $f$ is differentiable, it is also continuous; in particular, it is continuous on each compact interval $[a,b]\subset(0,\infty)$.

Comment: What do you mean by 'This shows that lim supx→∞|f(x)/x|≤ϵ'?

Comment: Did you mean This shows that lim x→∞|f(x)/x|≤ϵ?

Comment: How does one arrive at the first step (the first two sides of the first inequality) in this line: \begin{align*}
\left|\frac{f(x)}{x}\right|\leq\frac{1}{x}\left(\int_0^c|f'(t)|dt+\int_c^x|f'(x)|dt\right)\leq\frac{1}{x}\int_0^c|f'(t)|dt+\frac{(x-c)\epsilon}{x}\to\epsilon
\end{align*}
as $x\to\infty$ ?  Should it rather be that: \begin{align*}
\left|\frac{f(x)}{x}\right| = \frac{1}{x}\left(\int_0^c|f'(t)|dt+\int_c^x|f'(x)|dt\right)\leq\frac{1}{x}\int_0^c|f'(t)|dt+\frac{(x-c)\epsilon}{x}\to\epsilon
\end{align*}
as $x\to\infty$ ?

Comment: I added some more detail.

Comment: The additional detail is helpful.